# Cloning complex svn branch setup with git svn clone

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-clone

In our svn repo, I have branches located in `/branches`. I also have branches located in `/branches/subdir1` and `/branches/subdir2`. I have tried passing `--branches=/branches` but that doesn't get what is inside `subdir1` & `subdir2`. I have tried passing `branches=/branches branches=/branches/subdir1 branches=/branches/subdir2`, but that still treats `subdir1` & `subdir2` as their own branch. I have also tried `branches=/branches/*/*` but that had similar behavior. How can I get all of my branches?

Comment: Is this about a one-time conversion or do you want to use Git as front-end for the SVN repo, keeping the SVN as authorative code source and committing back from Git to SVN?

Answer (score 0):

I need to go back and forth for awhile and svn2git is not an option for me. I figured it out. You can specify specific branches by having a comma-separated list within braces. So my config lines had these related lines:
    `branches = branches/{branch1,branch2,branch3}:refs/remotes/*`
    `branches = branches/subdir1/*:refs/remotes/*`
    `branches = branches/subdir2/*:refs/remotes/*`